# Copy contents from an field entity reference

Tags: nodes

I have 2 content type

1-**Parent Product**
Title
Fabric Type
Product Type
Product Description

2-**Child Product**
ParentProduct (Node Reference to Parent Product Content Type)
Title
Fabric Type
Product Type
Product Description
Product Code
Product Size
Product Color


**Here is the use case**.
1-I Create all my Parent Product

2-I Create a child
The first field I need to filled is ParentProduct (Node Reference)
By choosing the ParentProduct, I would like  this parent act as the default value for Title, Fabric Type, Product Type and Product description of this child.

Is there any module that could help me for that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Using [Entityreference prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) and [Entityreference prepopulate token](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate_token)

Once installed, you will need to create a link for the Child on the Parent page's template that includes tokens for the fields you want prepopulated. The [answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120158/use-multiple-url-arguments-to-prepopulate-multiple-entity-reference-fields) shows how to string multiple values together.

If it needs use a Node Reference rather than an Entity Reference, then [Node Reference URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) Widget and [Prepopluate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) will do approximately the same thing.